# Hide specific element based on value from name attribute

Tags: jquery, html

I have HTML like this:

```
<div>
   <input name="studentName" value="George">
   <input name="studentName" value="Kim">
   <input name="studentName" value="David">
   <input name="studentName" value="Kanto">
</div>
```

How can I hide other input element except "David" using jQuery?

Comment: 1.  You could loop through all the inputs to find, then hide all but the one you want, but you're much better off giving each input a different name, otherwise you will have problems when you submit the form and need accurate data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `:not()`, [Attribute Equals Selector [name="value"]](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/), `.hide()`

```js
$("div input:not([value=David])").hide()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
   <input name="studentName" value="George">
   <input name="studentName" value="Kim">
   <input name="studentName" value="David">
   <input name="studentName" value="Kanto">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have another question.

If I have HTML like this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/xxdu0hgy/)

How can I only display value contains "david"

Comment: Which element should be displayed at https://jsfiddle.net/xxdu0hgy/? _"but I have another question"_ Does `javascript` at Answer resolve present Question?

Comment: Use a regex selector `"input[value^='David']"`

Comment: @Kim `div input:not([value^=David])`

Comment: @guest271314 now I have another problem, the selector is case sensitive.
How can I make that incase sensitive??

Comment: @Kim What do you mean?

Comment: @guest271314

input[value^='david'], can I make this 'David' become incase sensitive.

Comment: @Kim You can use `:not()` for each attribute selector `$("div input:not([value^=David]):not([value^=david])").hide()` https://jsfiddle.net/xxdu0hgy/2/

Comment: Can I make it dynamic, because I already built an search form which user can search student name

Comment: Not certain what you mean by "dynamic"? Perhaps consider forming single Question which includes all requirements?